# Why am I getting a type mismatch error?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-conversion

Here is my code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module StateParser where
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

newtype State s a = State {compute :: s -> (a, s)}

newtype StateM m s a = StateM {compute_M :: s -> m (a, s)}

result_s :: a -> State s a
result_s v = State (\s -> (v ,s))

bind_s :: State s a -> (a -> State s b) -> State s b
bind_s st f = State $ \s -> (\(v, s') -> compute (f v) s') (compute st s)

result_sm :: (Functor m) => a -> StateM m s a
result_sm v = StateM (\s -> result_s (v, s))

bind_sm :: (Functor m) => StateM m s a -> (a -> StateM m s b) -> StateM m s b
bind_sm stm f = StateM $ \s -> (tmp s `bind_sm` id)
  where
    tmp s = fmap (\(v, s') -> compute_M (f v) s') (compute_M stm s)

instance Functor (State s) where
  fmap f st = st >>= (pure . f)

instance Applicative (State s) where
  pure = result_s
  p <*> q = p >>= \f ->
            q >>= (pure . f)

instance Monad (State s) where
  --Explicit return definition only required for code required to be compatible
  --with GHC versions prior to 7.10. The default implementation for all GHC
  --versions from 7.10 is
  return = pure
  (>>=)  = bind_s

instance Functor f => Functor (StateM f s) where
  fmap f stm = stm `bind_sm` (result_sm . f)

instance Applicative f => Applicative (StateM f s) where
  pure = result_sm
  p <*> q = p `bind_sm` \f ->
            q `bind_sm` (pure . f)

instance Monad m => Monad (StateM m s) where
  return = pure
  (>>=)  = bind_sm
```

When compiling, I get 2 type mismatch errors:

```
StateParser.hs:43:29
    Couldn't match type `m' with `State s1'
      `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for result_sm :: Functor m => a -> StateM m s a
          at StateParser.hs:42:14
    Expected type: m (a, s)
      Actual type: State s1 (a, s)
    ...
    In the expression: result_s (v, s)
    In the first argument of `StateM', namely
      `(\ s -> result_s (v, s))'

StateParser.hs:46:33:
    Couldn't match type `m' with `StateM m0 s0'
      `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            bind_sm :: Functor m =>
                       StateM m s a -> (a -> StateM m s b) -> StateM m s b
          at StateParser.hs:45:12
    Expected type: StateM m0 s0 (m (b, s))
      Actual type: m (m (b, s))
    ...
    In the first argument of `bind_sm', namely `tmp s'
    In the expression: (tmp s `bind_sm` id)
```

However, I have very clearly defined instances of the `Functor` typeclass for the type constructors `State s` and `StateM f s`, which should allow them to match with the type variable `m`, bound by the `Functor` typeclass in `bind_sm` and `result_sm`.

There is probably some aspect of Haskell's type inference procedures of which I am unaware. Will someone enlighten me?

Comment: There is no magic happening here - your function is simply wrong (not type correct), and the typechecker is perfectly right to reject it. Since the compiler already told you precisely why the program is incorrect, have you tried fixing the things it tells you are wrong? (Have you read the error?) At the very least, `StateM $ \s -> .. \`bind_sm\` ..` means that `StateM` should have type `s -> StateM m0 x0 (StateM m1 x1 (a,s))` which it clearly does not.

Answer (score 4):

```
result_sm v = StateM (\s -> result_s (v, s))
```

Looks wrong to me. The function

```
\s -> result_s (v, s)
```

has type

```
s -> State s (a,s)
```

while `StateM` expects

```
s -> m (a,s)
```

for any arbitrary `m`, not just `m ~ State s`.

Are you sure you don't want something like:

```
result_sm :: (Monad m) => a -> StateM m s a
result_sm v = StateM (\s -> return (v, s))
```

(or an applicative variant)?

Comment: Are the errors related to the code above, or to the users. The latter is understandable, since the type signature had to be changed.

Comment: @UnchartedWaters, you are not being very helpful to your own cause. The code @chi showed you does fix the problem with `result_sm` as demonstrated here: http://lpaste.net/180892 You have other problems with `bind_sm` and other areas, but this is a fix for your first error.